# Composer update failed: the "/home/myself/.composer/cache" directory used to download the temp file could not be written

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to install CakePHP but on [launching](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html):

```
composer self-update && composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app my_app_name
```

I got this error message:

```
[Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]                                    
  Filesystem exception:                                                        
  Composer update failed: the "/home/myself/.composer/cache" directory use  
  d to download the temp file could not be written
```

How to fix it?

Comment: tell the Composer guys to fix their effing error messages. it doesn't say WHY it can't be written, simply that it can't. they should have added the f****** reason why, but they did not. most likely, it's permission denied, which could be solved as "chmod 777 /home/myself/" , but it could also be an out-of-disk error. because of Composer's shitty error report, there's no way to tell from that error.

Comment: @hanshenrik you are right, the chmod resolved the problem, thank you